# How to add frameworks to Xcode 7?

Tags: xcode7

I'm unable to find and add AVFoundation framework and other frameworks in Xcode 7 beta like we were able to do on Xcode 6.

How can I add AVFoundation to the project, in Xcode 7 (beta)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On the left column, select your project. There is an icon/button with your project's name in the right pane. Click the  UpDown icon and change from Project to Target. Then go to the General tab, scroll down to the Frameworks section and add/remove Frameworks.

Answer (score 5):

Apple added a new feature called [module](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html) which is semantic to import. It's kind of a better implementation of the pre-compiled headers.

Modules are a packaging together of the framework executable and it's headers.

One of the big advantages of using `@import` is that you don't need to add the framework in the project settings, it's done automatically.

Add any framework like below,

[image]

Comment: Hold Command button & press on the imported framework, It will re-direct you to that class header file.

Comment: This is no good for adding external frameworks into a project with XCode 7 - only XCode 7 built in libraries can be added this way.

Answer (score 3):

Click on your project icon, then under TARGETS select Tests, then select Build Phases, select Link Binary With Libraries, add the framework you need.